# How BFS can from a tree on certain directed graph?

Tags: breadth-first-search

It is said said BFS always gives a tree, while DFS gives a forest.
But I do not understand how BFS can always give a tree. 
Consider this graph and starting point b

[image]

How do we get a tree here?

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why you have a directed graph and an terminal starting point b.
From b, it can go nowhere but stay at b.

If it not directed, then it will be b->a->c->d, no matter it is BFS or DFS.

First time heard DFS returns a forest. Guess people think this because every time it reaches end it will return to parent node.

Answer (score 0):

A tree is basically a connected graph(at least one path between every pair of nodes) with no cycles.

If we do BFS on a connected graph, we will visit every node in the graph and each node is visited only once. So, there is only one path from starting node to every node we visit, since we visit it only once. There is also only one path between any pair of nodes by same argument as above (it will make more sense if you imagine a graph and comprehend). So, there are no cycles and hence it's a tree.

Answer (score 0):

BFS not gives a tree. It use queue ,in fact. And alongside with DFS, BFS is also an algorithm to go through the tree.